# How does an iBeacon/sender/receiver handle collisions?

Tags: protocols, collision, ibeacon

What is the theoretical/practical limit to the number of ibeacons you can have within their broadcasting range; there must be one. And what do they do, if anything to compensate should their signal constantly collide with another, unsure if they even know?

Imagine you have 30 beacons within the same venue, say in a large open space, they are all transmitting once a second, so there is a 1 in 2 chance their signals will collide. How does that work practically speaking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no hard limits, but **you will begin to see reduced performance when you have hundreds of beacons transmitting in the same radio range.**

There are two limits you will run into with beacon density:

1. **Radio collisions.**  Bluetooth chipsets avoid collisions in their advertisements by slightly randomizing when packets are broadcast and waiting to transmit when another signal is detected on the same channel.  At high densities (100s of transmitters in range), this will start to reduce the number of packets that get sent out making beacon receivers get fewer packets.  At first, this means fewer samples for distance estimates **yielding poorer distance estimates.**  Ultimately, it causes **delays in detections**.  See: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21991/how-many-active-bluetooth-devices-can-i-reliably-detect-in-a-single-space
2. **Receiver processing limits.**  Different receivers will start dropping Bluetooth packets when they cannot keep up due to processing limits.  As @heypiotr notes, faster processors (both in the Bluetooth chipset and the mobile device main CPU) can successfully get more packets and track more beacons.  An iPhone 4S device can track around 100 beacons before some get dropped.  Newer devices can track more.

Answer (score 2):

From my own experience, it's actually the mobile device's hardware & computational capacity that put a limit on the number of beacons that can be discovered. We've tested this in the past and e.g. iPhone 5C seems to be capable of handling 80–100 Bluetooth devices at a time, while iPhone 6 Plus could process around 200 of them. What this means in practice is, once you hit the limit, some of the beacons might not get discovered.